# MySQL regexp how to "if"

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to skip words DORM, Dorm and dorm using regexp but keep them if there is word PREMIUM, Premium or premium after that. How do I do that? As I understood I can skip "DORM, Dorm and dorm" with this regex `(^DORM|Dorm|dorm)` but how do I do that "if" thing after that?

Comment: What do you mean, "skip using regexp"? select all records where a certain field doesn't include "dorm"? Also, `(^DORM|Dorm|dorm)` is a strange regexp, which matches `DORM` at start of string, but `Dorm` or `dorm` anywhere in string...?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Please post more code so we can see the context

Comment: Does "DORM" need to be at the beginning of the string, or can it be anywhere in the string?

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to let the collation (a collation ending in `ci`) do the case folding for you.  If that is OK with you, then this might be the simplest:

```
WHERE str LIKE '%dorm%premium%'
```

The equivalent regexp is slower:

```
WHERE str REGEXP 'dorm.*premium'
```

But, if you need word boundaries, this works in `regexp`, but not `like`:

```
WHERE str REGEXP '[[:<:]]dorm[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]premium[[:>:]]'
```

There are many problems with the Question (and hence with my Answer):

- Why did you have the "anchor" (`^`) in front of `DORM`, but not the others?
- What if the word `dormitory` is in the string?
- How should `doRM` be treated?
- Is there a reason for insisting on regexp?
- What did you mean by "skip words"?  A `REGEXP` (or `LIKE`), when used in a `WHERE` clause "skips rows".